# ASP.NET ConfirmButtonExtender No Background in IE

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-ajax

I'm using the ConfirmButtonExtender on a Cancel button.  Until recently I'd been running this code in Firefox and it was displaying just right (semi transparent background, simple modal popup).

However when I switched over to test this in IE, I get the generic looking 'javascript-style-alert-box" instead.

The ModalPopupExtender seems to work in both browsers correctly and I'm guessing that's because you have more control over the CSS with that (not sure though).

Have others ran into this issue with the ConfirmButtonExtender?  I just wanted to check to see if there is a fix before I switch over to the ModalPopupExtender instead.

```
<div class="base-container-controls-100pct">
    <asp:Button ID="UxCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="button-sm" OnClick="UxCancelClick" />
    <asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="UxCancel">
    </asp:ConfirmButtonExtender>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button, .button-sm, .button-ms, .button-md, .button-lg, .button-xl, .button-disabled, .button-status-close,
.button-grid, .button-grid-sm, .button-grid-ms, .button-grid-md, .button-grid-lg, .button-grid-xl
{   
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #0088C2;

    color: #f2f2f2;

    border-color: #DDDDDD #AAAAAA #AAAAAA #DDDDDD; 
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: none;

    font-size: .8em;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 2px 12px 2px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-user-select: none;
}

.button-grid, .button-grid-sm, .button-grid-ms, .button-grid-md, .button-grid-lg, .button-grid-xl 
{
    height: 25px;
    font-size: .8em;    
}

.button-sm, .button-grid-sm 
{
    width: 75px;
}

        .base-container-controls-100pct
    {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        border: none;
        height: auto;
    }
```

Comment: The CSS for my button?  I'll add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it uses the standard Javascript `window.confirm()` (which is sounds like it does) then you have no control over the way it looks, as that is built into the browser itself. Firefox and Chrome (maybe others) changed the look of that from old popup javascript style alert box to a little nicer style a couple years ago. IE is still using the old standard style which you are seeing.

Sounds like you'll have to make a switch if you want to have more control over the look.